# OpenSSL handshake error, no shared cipher

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, handshake

I'm trying to make a client/server program with the OpenSSL that can set up a secure connection and then pass encrypted messages back and forth. I'm using a self-signed certificate for the server and a private key for the client. When a connection is established, I use `SSL_accept()` to initiate the handshake. This is where the program breaks. On the client-side, the error message is:

`140104940065408:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 40`

and on the server-side the error message is:

`140062094398080:error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher:../ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:2283:`

I'm very new to OpenSSL and to cryptography in general so I'm quite lost as to how to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll post the full code for the client and server below.

Client Program:

```
#include <errno.h> /*USING THE ERROR LIBRARY FOR FINDING ERRORS*/
#include <stdio.h> /*standard i/o*/
#include <unistd.h> /*FOR USING FORK for at a time send and receive messages*/ 
#include <malloc.h> /*FOR MEMORY ALLOCATION */
#include <string.h> /*using fgets funtions for geting input from user*/
#include <sys/socket.h> /*for creating sockets*/
#include <resolv.h> /*server to find out the runner's IP address*/ 
#include <netdb.h> /*definitions for network database operations */
#include <openssl/ssl.h> /*using openssl function's and certificates and configuring them*/
#include <openssl/err.h> /* helps in finding out openssl errors*/
#include <unistd.h>  /*FOR USING FORK for at a time send and receive messages*/ 
#define FAIL    -1 /*for error output == -1 */
#define BUFFER  1024  /*buffer for reading messages*/

// CLIENT PROGRAM

//code from: https://github.com/ElectronSz/Encrypted-Chat-Server-Using-C-Programming-and-OpenSSL-AES-DES

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port) {   
    int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;   /*creating the sockets*/

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL ) {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   /* setting the connection as tcp it creates endpoint for connection */
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )  /*initiate a connection on a socket*/ {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

void LoadKey(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* KeyFile)   /* to load a certificate into an SSL_CTX structure*/ {
    
    /* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)     /*creating and setting up ssl context structure*/ {   
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = TLS_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */

    if ( ctx == NULL ) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)  /*show the ceritficates to server and match them but here we are not using any client certificate*/ {   
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;
    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL ) {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    } else {
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
    }
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])   /* getting port and ip as an argument*/ {   
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    char input[BUFFER];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname, *portnum;
    pid_t cpid;     /* fork variable*/

    if ( count != 3 ) {
        printf("usage: %s  \n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();   /*load encryption and hash algo's in ssl*/
    hostname=strings[1];
    portnum=strings[2];
    ctx = InitCTX();
    //SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites(ctx, OSSL_default_ciphersuites());
    LoadKey(ctx, "client.pem"); /* load certs */
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));   /*converting ascii port to interger */
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    //SSL_set_ciphersuites(ssl, OSSL_default_ciphersuites());
    /* Host common name */
    // Not necessarily needed
    //SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, "Conor");
    
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */ {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    } else {
        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);
        /* get any certs */
        cpid=fork();
        /*Fork system call is used to create a new process*/
        if(cpid==0) {
            while(1) {
                fflush(stdout);
                printf("\nMESSAGE TO SERVER:");
                fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);
                SSL_write(ssl, input, strlen(input));   /* encrypt & send message */
            }
        } else {
            while(1) {
                bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request */
                if ( bytes > 0 ) { 
                    buf[bytes] = 0;
                    printf("\nMESSAGE FROM SERVER: %s\n", buf);
                    printf("\nMESSAGE TO SERVER:");
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
            } 
        }
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */
    }   
    close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

Server Program:

```
//#include <openssl/applink.c>
#include <unistd.h> /*FOR USING FORK for at a time send and receive messages*/ 
#include <errno.h>   /*USING THE ERROR LIBRARY FOR FINDING ERRORS*/
#include <malloc.h>  /*FOR MEMORY ALLOCATION */
#include <string.h>  /*using fgets funtions for geting input from user*/
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /*for using ascii to network bit*/ 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>        /* network to asii bit */
#include <resolv.h>  /*server to find out the runner's IP address*/ 
#include <stdio.h>   /*standard i/o*/
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define FAIL    -1  /*for error output == -1 */
#define BUFFER 1024  /*buffer for reading messages*/

// SERVER PROGRAM

void InitializeSSL() {
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
}

void DestroySSL() {
    ERR_free_strings();
    EVP_cleanup();
}

void ShutdownSSL(SSL* cSSL) {
    SSL_shutdown(cSSL);
    SSL_free(cSSL);
}

int OpenListener(int port)   {   
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;   /*creating the sockets*/
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));    /*free output the garbage space in memory*/
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    /*getting ip address form machine */
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);   /* converting host bit to n/w bit */
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    
    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) /* assiging the ip address and port*/ {
        perror("can't bind port");    /* reporting error using errno.h library */
        abort();      /*if error will be there then abort the process */
    }

    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )     /*for listening to max of 10 clients in the queue*/ {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");  /* reporting error using errno.h library */
        abort();      /*if erroor will be there then abort the process */
    }
    return sd;
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */ {   
    char buf[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    char input[BUFFER];  
    pid_t cpid; 
    //Here is the SSL Accept portion.  Now all reads and writes must use SSL
    int ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    if (ret == 0) {
        /* Hard error */
        exit(-1);
    } else if ( ret == -1 )     /* do SSL-protocol accept */ {
        printf("Handshake Error %d\n", SSL_get_error(ssl, ret));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    /*Fork system call is used to create a new process*/
    cpid=fork();
    if(cpid==0) { 
        while(1) {
            bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get request and read message from server*/
            if ( bytes > 0 ) { 
                buf[bytes] = 0;
                printf("\nMESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buf);
                printf("\nMESSAGE TO CLIENT:");
                fflush(stdout);
            } else {
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            }
        } 
    } else {
        while(1) {
            fflush(stdout);
            printf("\nMESSAGE TO CLIENT:");
            fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin);  /* get request and reply to client*/
            SSL_write(ssl, input, strlen(input)); 
        }  
    }

    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* get socket connection */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* release SSL state */
    close(sd);          /* close connection */
}

bool str_to_uint16(char *str, uint16_t *res) {
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    intmax_t val = strtoimax(str, &end, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || val < 0 || val > UINT16_MAX || end == str || *end != '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    *res = (uint16_t) val;
    return true;
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])   /* getting port as a argument*/ {   
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    SSL_CTX *sslctx;
    SSL *cSSL;
    char buf[1024];
    char input[BUFFER];
    int bytes;
    char *portnum;
    pid_t cpid;     /* fork variable*/
    if ( count != 2 ) {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum> \n", strings[0]);   /*send the usage guide if syntax of setting port is different*/
        exit(0);
    }
    
    portnum = strings[1];
    uint16_t temp;
    uint16_t *aPortNumber = &temp;
    if (str_to_uint16(portnum, aPortNumber) == false) {
        printf("Port number must be between 0 and 65535.");
        exit(1);
    }
    InitializeSSL();
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd< 0) {
        //Log and Error
        exit(1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in saiServerAddress;
    bzero((char *) &saiServerAddress, sizeof(saiServerAddress));
    saiServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saiServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    saiServerAddress.sin_port = htons(*aPortNumber);

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &saiServerAddress, sizeof(saiServerAddress));

    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(cli_addr);
    listen(sockfd,5);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &len);

    sslctx = SSL_CTX_new( TLS_server_method());
    
    // check return values vvvv
    int use_cert = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, "server.pem" , SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if (use_cert == 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    int use_prv = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslctx, "private-key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if (use_prv == 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }

    cSSL = SSL_new(sslctx);
    SSL_set_fd(cSSL, newsockfd );
    //SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites(sslctx, cipher_list.c_str());
    //SSL_set_ciphersuites(cSSL, cipher_list.c_str());
    Servlet(cSSL);
    ShutdownSSL(cSSL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the server you don't check the return values of `_use_PrivateKey_file` and `_use_certificate_file`; you should, and if zero, print the error stack. If (either) failed, OpenSSL cannot support authenticated ciphersuites, and by default the client only offers authenticated ciphersuites, leading to 'no shared cipher'. Also, `OP_SINGLE_DH_USE` is obsolete in 1.1.0 up (which you are obviously using) and even before that only had effect if you set a DH keypair, which your code doesn't do. And your client needs to set a 'verify location' (truststore) that includes the server cert.

Comment: Also FYI in C `char foo[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};` is _exactly_ the same as `char foo[] = "abc";` which is much easier to type and read. Conversely `const char commonname[] = {'C', 'o', 'n', 'o', 'r'};` does NOT create a valid C string, so passing it to `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` which requires a C string causes Undefined Behavior -- which in theory could destroy the universe but in practice usually just randomly screws up or possibly crashes. Although for your server code, there is no need to set [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which is what `tlsext_host_name` does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the advice. I edited my code above to try and reflect the things you said, but I'm still getting the same error. Can you elaborate on what you mean by the client only offering authenticated cyphersuites?

Comment: You've changed the server to check the result from `_use_certificate_file` -- but not call `_use_PrivateKey_file` at all! You need to call _and_ check _both_. Authenticated ciphersuites are those that verify the identity of the server; TLS below 1.3 defines some ciphersuites that do not authenticate, but in most situations they are not secure so OpenSSL by default disables them. OpenSSL does _implement_ them, and you can explicitly enable them if you are in a rare situation where they are appropriate _and_ you control both client and server.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ah ok I added the `_use_PrivateKey_file` back in. Do I choose the ciphersuite when I'm generating the certificate? I'm still a little confused. I made a new key and certificate with the following commands:

`openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -out key.pem`,  `openssl req -new -sha256 -key key.pem -out csr.csr`,  `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem` 
 and it fixed my problem although I can't remember what I used for my old certificate.

Comment: In TLS1.2 and below, the certificate doesn't select or specify _a_ (single) ciphersuite, but it _constrains_ the ciphersuite: for example there are several dozen ciphersuites that require an RSA cert (and key), several for DSA, and several for sign-capable EC (the case you just did, often abbreviated ECDSA). In TLS1.3 the ciphersuite is not affected by the certificate; the authentication (aka signature) algorithm _does_ depend on the certificate but is now separate from the ciphersuite.

Comment: Also I realized I was wrong to say your client 'needs' to set verify location. That would be needed _if_ you set verify _mode_, but you don't. As it stands,  your connections will work without verification, but depending on your network could be intercepted, eavesdropped on, and tampered with, and in short not provide the security people usually want from SSL/TLS.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I just have one other question: why exactly do we need to check the private key file on the server side? I assumed only clients would need a private key since the server already has a certificate